# Is indexing binary?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index

**The scenario:** 
When a user updates some information - the correct row must be found and updated.

I'm debating between two options:

1. Let the server search through all of the rows (-slow). But be fast on the
   update.
2. **Index**, and therefore be fast to find, but slow to update.

It seems that if the index is a binary tree - updating will be quick and therefore indexing  is better. And if not - not-indexing would be better because indexing will lose more when updating than gain when searching.

<sup>(Note that every user-action here will have both a search and an update.)</sup>

More info:

- I'm referring mainly to non-clustered indexing.
- Currently there are very few rows so it's difficult to assess the
  speed if and when  there will be over 1-10 million rows.

Comment: Shouldn't be difficult to assess the speed. You have some idea of what your data looks like, right? So generate a lot of it on a test system.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks. That sounds like sound advice. (Though, I'd still be interested in the answer to my question.)

Comment: I'd still be interested in what your actual question is. :-)

Comment: And the index is not a binary tree, but a balanced tree.  One of many explanations: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree

Comment: If/how much to index has the classic SQL Server answer: It Depends™. How much/how often do you do inserts, updates, what kind of queries do you run, how selective is your data, how much concurrency will you have, and a million other questions you don't answer here.

Comment: SQL Server indexing uses a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), not a binary tree. In general, indexes speed up searches and sorts and joins and slow down modifications. How much indexing you need depends on your application.

Comment: @RLF Thanks. You can transform your comment to an answer. That seems to be it.

Comment: @JNK Yes. "It depends" is usually the answer. I'm trying to get more information to make an informed decision. As for some of your detailed question: `how often...` - Why would the frequency of inserts matter? `what kind of queries` - Mainly the one mentioned (and yes - if a row isn't found - it becomes an insert.) `how much concurrency` - very good point. Thanks.

Comment: the frequency of inserts matters in relation to the other queries.  If you are inserting 1m records a minute and only querying every 30 minutes you will want a different structure than if you insert 100 records an hour and query it constantly.

Comment: @JNK An insert will only occur after a search has failed to find an appropriate row. Now I understand your comment regarding it. Thanks again.

Comment: Searching without an index is O(N) and inserting is O(k).  Searching with an index is O(logN) and inserting is O(logN).  This is usually seen as hugely positive trade-off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server B-Tree indexes are not binary trees, but balanced trees.  This structure allows a tree traversal which is much more shallow, and therefore likely results in a more rapid index search. This also affects the scope of updates to the indexes.

See one explanation at: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree

Comment: Even if DBMS were using binary trees, we'd still have logarithimic gain.